# "A registration already exists for URI" when using HttpSelfHostServer

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We are having an issue unit test failing because previous tests haven't closed session of `HttpSelfHostServer`.

So the second time we try to open a connection to a sever we get this message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : A registration already exists for URI 'http://localhost:1337/'.
```

This test forces the issue (as an example):

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class DuplicatHostIssue 
    {
    public HttpSelfHostServer _server;

    [Test]
    public void please_work()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:1337/");
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync().Wait();

        config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:1337/");
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

So newing up a new instance of the server dosent seem to kill the previous session. Any idea how to force the desposal of the previous session?

Full exception if it helps?

```
      System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.   ----> System.InvalidOperationException : A registration already exists for URI 'http://localhost:1337/'.    
    at 

System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    
at ANW.API.Tests.Acceptance.DuplicatHostIssue.please_work() in DuplicatHostIssue.cs: line 32
    --InvalidOperationException    
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)    
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result) 
at System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer.OpenListenerComplete(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: One way you could avoid this issue is to use an in-memory host to do your unit tests.  It would make your tests run faster too!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to write a Dispose method like below and call it appropriately to avoid this issue

```
private static void HttpSelfHostServerDispose()
{
    if (server != null)
    {
        _server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        _server.Dispose();
        _server = null;
    }
}
```

This will clear the URI register.